# CSS background without using url

Tags: css

Is there a way in CSS to include a background without using url()

Ex, I can't do this:

```
#blah {
    background:url("either image or image data");
}
```

Is there a workaround where I can achieve the same thing but not using the keyword "url" (The word "url" is prohibited.

Comment: why "url" word is prohibited?

Comment: Very good question, some sanitizing filter is blocking it. This is on a website that I have 0 control over

Comment: That's the most ridiculous I've ever heard. Blocking url is breaking CSS.

Comment: Would embedding an image into html be a solution? .. it can be used as background within a div or anything else you can do with a normal img tag

Comment: unfortunately I can only add css code, the website does not allow html

Comment: So how do you add the ccs you are allowed put on this rather strange website .. and does this website has a name?

Comment: Do you have access to the head tag so you can add a css link to your file like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />`

Comment: All that I have access to is a single textarea that I can globally define CSS from. The website is: https://stonybrook.digication.com/dashboard

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `<img>` tag as your background image, no URL in the CSS is necessary. Something like this:

HTML

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="bg">
<div id="page-wrap">
</div>
```

CSS

```
img.bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;
    }
}
```

See here for more information and a demo: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot. That is the way CSS works when including external content. To prohibit the keyword url on the web is a rather strange thing.

Answer (score -2):

No need to make it so complicated !!!

Here is the explanation  :
When using the url() value, you have three choices:

- **relative path based on the root domain** of the CSS file — begin with a slash (/) as shown above
- **relative path based on the immediate directory of the CSS file** — no slash (url(path/to/image.png) )
- **absolute URL**, if you are linking to an external resource — url(http://example.com/path/to/image.png)

Source: https://html.com/attributes/body-background/

So basically, if you have your image in the folder image, next to to the foler styles (in which you css file might be), here is what you need to do :
**background: url(../images/Chat.jpg)**
../ means you go back one level above your current folder/workplace.

Here is what I used:

```css
background: url(../images/Chat.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

Comment: You used the string `url` which the question explicitly states (**four times!**) they cannot because a filter blocks it.